# min date doesn't disable past dates in ionic 3

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ion-datetime with moment.js to pick a date in hours and the min value doesn't recognize the format

I have already look on many stack overflow answers to this problem but the solutions don't work.

the most common solution its to put this minDate =  new Date().toISOString()
but still not working

my .ts code:

```
 minDate =  new Date().toISOString();
```

my .html code:

```
<ion-datetime  displayFormat="hh:mm A" pickerFormat="hh:mm A" [(ngModel)]="startHour" [min]="minDate " ></ion-datetime>
```

This is the error, I have tried in the HTML without the brackets like this min="minDate" and still, I get an error

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkD0k.jpg)

I have also tried with moment.js

```
  minDate =  moment().format('HH');
```

and doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try removing space from minDate somehow is being read as another variable.

```
<ion-datetime  displayFormat="hh:mm A" pickerFormat="hh:mm A" [(ngModel)]="startHour" [min]="minDate" ></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: thanks for responding, I tried your answer with and without the brackets and the extra space of minDate that you found but  still i get error with moment.js and Date, the error i get is:  "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of null"

Comment: @DanielAltamar also in your ts fiel you can set minDate = new Date() should be fine without to format the date

Comment: didn't worked, it appears the same error  "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of null"  :(